# Autoexpand UITextView height dynamically in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a simple textView who's data gets populated dynamically. I want to resize the height of the textview once the data is populated so that I don't see a vertical scroll nor the text gets clipped.i want to do this task programatically. I have a label which should be placed 20 px below height of textview like "interested".

This is my code:

```
lblHobbies = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 310, 300, 20)];
lblHobbies.text=@"Hobbies";
lblHobbies.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
lblHobbies.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f/255.0f green:153.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

[scrollView addSubview:lblHobbies];

tViewhobbies=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 330, 300, 60)];
tViewhobbies.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
tViewhobbies.layer.cornerRadius=5;
[tViewhobbies setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]];
[tViewhobbies setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

tViewhobbies.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
tViewhobbies.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];

tViewhobbies.delegate=self;

tViewhobbies.scrollEnabled=YES;

[scrollView addSubview:tViewhobbies];

lblInterests = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 370, 300, 20)];            
lblInterests.text=@"Interests";
lblInterests.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
lblInterests.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f/255.0f green:153.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1];

[scrollView addSubview:lblInterests];


tViewInterests=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 390, 300, 60)];
tViewInterests.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[tViewInterests setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]];
[tViewInterests setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
tViewInterests.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];      
tViewInterests.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];

tViewInterests.delegate=self;

tViewInterests.scrollEnabled=YES;

[scrollView addSubview:tViewInterests];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by sizeToFit method of UITextview.

```
[myTextView sizeToFit];
```

Comment: thanks for your response.already i wrote this line of code.But it is not worked.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on font size. Following code retrieve the font size of text and return the height and width required. This may help you to create the logic:

```
NSDictionary *attribs1 = @{
                          NSFontAttributeName: tViewhobbies.font
                          };

CGSize textViewSize = [tViewhobbies.text sizeWithAttributes:attribs1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is  the trick I always use...

1. Create one fake `UITextView`
2. Put data into it
3. Call sizeToFit
4. Hide this textview
5. Set actual textview height based on this fake uitextview...

Done....

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
tViewhobbies=[[UITextView alloc]init];
    tViewhobbies.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [tViewhobbies setText:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."];
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(300.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize requiredSize = [tViewhobbies sizeThatFits:maxSize];
    tViewhobbies.frame = CGRectMake(10,330, requiredSize.width, requiredSize.height);
    tViewhobbies.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    [tViewhobbies setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    tViewhobbies.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    tViewhobbies.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];
    tViewhobbies.delegate=self;
    tViewhobbies.scrollEnabled=NO;
    [scrollView addSubview:tViewhobbies];
    [tViewhobbies sizeToFit];
```

First you have to assign the text before setting its frame for calculating its frame and than you can do `sizeToFit`. I am sure it'll work. And all below labels or textviews' y position should be relative to that textview.

Comment: thanks for your response.It will not worked for me brother.Please tell me any other way..

Comment: yes brother.But the problem is the textview will not displayed.that is the problem...

Comment: I am getting this http://prntscr.com/2pzukj with above code. Is that what you want right?

Comment: yes brother. i am getting data from webservices.and that data is displayed in uitextview.so i want to display Data in UITextview dynamically....

Comment: So what's the problem than? Just replace the text with whatever you are getting from web service. I think you should check your webservice  response whether you are getting any data in it or not?

Comment: brother ur sending code will not work.IF I paste ur code the textview will not displayed in View.If i wrote my code the textview will displayed.But I have a label which should be placed 20 px below height of textview like "interested".The hobbies textview will replace the interested textview.i wrote this code.I have a label which should be placed 20 px below height of textview like "interested".