# how to make AutoExpand UITextView Dynamically in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a simple textView who's data gets populated dynamically.I want to resize the height of the textview once the data is populated so that I don't see a vertical scroll nor the text gets clipped.i have two textfields like hobbies and interested and corresponding labels like hobbies and interested.Yesterday also posted this Query.But i am not get any solution.I want to display interested label and interested textview automatically based on Hobbies textview.Please help me anybody.I Struck this issue yesterday onwards.Please give me guidance anybody. Thanks in advance.

```
tViewhobbies=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 330, 300, 60)];
tViewhobbies.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
tViewhobbies.layer.cornerRadius=5;
[tViewhobbies setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]];
[tViewhobbies setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
tViewhobbies.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
tViewhobbies.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];
tViewhobbies.delegate=self;
tViewhobbies.scrollEnabled=YES;
[scrollView addSubview:tViewhobbies];
lblInterests = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 370, 300, 20)];            
lblInterests.text=@"Interests";
lblInterests.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
lblInterests.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f/255.0f green:153.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1];
[scrollView addSubview:lblInterests];

tViewInterests=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 390, 300, 60)];
tViewInterests.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[tViewInterests setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]];
[tViewInterests setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
tViewInterests.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];      
tViewInterests.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];
tViewInterests.delegate=self;
tViewInterests.scrollEnabled=YES;
[scrollView addSubview:tViewInterests];
```

Comment: Do not ask same question twice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601478/autoexpand-uitextview-height-dynamically-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set

```
[tViewInterests sizeToFit];
[tViewInterests layoutIfNeeded];
```